# How can I tweak this git log command / bash script to include deleted commits from deleted branches that git reflog should still know about?

Tags: bash, git, git-log, git-reflog

So I have this little bash script to output a csv file that shows all my commit history from a specific month.

```bash
function make-git-report() {
  if [ "$1" != "" ]
  then
    local month=$1
  else
    local month=$(date +%m)
  fi

  local year=$(date +%Y)
  local nextYear=$year
  local nextMonth=$((month+1))

  if [ "$nextMonth" = "13" ]
  then
    local nextMonth="01"
    local nextYear=$((year+1))
  fi

  local start="$year-$month-01"
  local end="$nextYear-$nextMonth-01"

  rm -f log.csv
  git --no-pager log \
      --author="Evert" \
      --since="$start" \
      --before="$end" \
      --branches --remotes --tags --no-decorate --no-merges \
      --pretty=format:'§"%ch";"%an";"%s";' --stat | \
      grep -v \| | tr -s "\n\n"  | tr "\n" '"' | tr "§" "\n" > templog.csv
  echo "\nDate;Author;Message;Changes" >> templog.csv
  tac templog.csv > log.csv
  rm -f templog.csv
}
```

But I just realized that if a branch is deleted during that month, and it was only merged using a squash merge, then a lot of commits will not show up in my csv file.

I've understood that `git reflog` will somehow still contain that missing data, but I'm not sure how to merge that information into the output from `git log` while graciously avoiding things like duplicate entries and maybe more unwanted results that I now can't think of.

Can anybody give me a little hint, a push in the right direction, on how to solve this?

Comment: to avoid `grep -v \|`, you may want to use `--shortstat` instead of `--stat`. You may also skip the templog + `tac` step, by putting the title line first, and use `git log --reverse`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the reflog to reliably get information about deleted branches :

- the log gets updated only if you see the commit at all
  e.g : if you take 2 days off, your local repo will have no trace of what happened during those two days ...
- two clones of the same repo will not have the same reflog
- the reflog will also contain information about rebased/cherry-picked commit (and possibly add duplicate information on the log you are trying to build ?)
- the reflog for HEAD will stay around, but reflog for specific branches/remote branches will get deleted if said branch is deleted too
- etc ...

---

I guess you describe a workflow based around a known git central service (github ? gitlab ? azure devops ? ...) where your branches get merged via pull requests.

Each of these services keep a link to the branch of its pull requests :

- a generic way to see that is to run `git ls-remote`, and see what refs are listed (you should see a list of `refs/pull/xxx/...` or `refs/merge-requests/xxx/...` or ...)
- and read the documentation for said service

You can fetch these pull requests :

```
# with this refspec : all pull requests will be stored under origin/pull/*,
# as if they were remote branches
git fetch origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull/*

# or you may choose to store them in a different set of refs :
git fetch origin +refs/pull/*:refs/pull/*
```

You may also use the API of said service to check the state of a pull request.

Combining the information above, you may choose, pull request by pull request, whether you should add `pull/xyz/head` to the list of refs in your `git log` command or not.

---

note that, if your branch are squash merged, the "merge commits" will actually *not* be merge commits, so you would have to choose another way than `--no-merges` to exclude them from your log (for example : print the commits sha and skip the ones that are known to be a merge request result)